# How to have bold unit with Siunitx

Tags: siunitx, bold

My question is relatively simple, but after reading the new `siunitx` documentation, I still don't have the answer.

How to make, in math mode, that the unit is sensitive to the commands `\mathbf` and `\symbf` and thus have units written in bold ?

For numbers, it works well, so I don't understand why it is not the case with units.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec, unicode-math, siunitx}

\sisetup{
mode=match,
reset-text-family = false ,
reset-text-series = false ,
reset-text-shape = false,
text-family-to-math = false ,
text-series-to-math = false,
propagate-math-font = true,
reset-math-version = false
}

\begin{document}

\noindent
xxxx $\mathbf{2 x = \qty{10}{\kilo\gram}}$ xxxx\\
xxxx $\symbf{2 x = \qty{10}{\kilo\gram}}$ xxxx.\\

\noindent
What I would like to have:\\
xxxx $\symbf{2 x = 10\, kg}$ xxxx.\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think there's one bug in this area, but doesn't directly impact your case: I'll check on the code, fix what I think is up then answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have logged the initial issue as https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/issues/525. The reason this arises here is that the 'referenece' output here is `10\,\mathrm{kg}`, and so we end up with `\mathbf{10\,\mathrm{kg}}` and get inconsistent bold.

The intention for `propagate-math-font` is that it covers font family, rather than other aspects: I should make this clearer. I will think about how best to address the issue, as there are arguments both ways here.

What I would say is that making math mode text bold is a job for `\boldmath`. I'd therefore expect to use

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{reset-math-version = false}
\begin{document}
xxxx {\boldmath$2 x = \qty{10}{\kilo\gram}$} xxxx
\end{document}
```

here, perhaps with `\mathbf` around the `x` depending on the semantics. (`\boldmath` is essentially about appearance, `\mathbf` is suggesting that there is mathematical meaning to the choice of font.)

---

All that said, I've decided that I will extend the code here to cover `\mathbf`. Until that hits CTAN, you can use

```latex
\cs_gset_protected:Npn \__siunitx_print_math_auxiv:n #1
  {
    \bool_if:NTF \l__siunitx_print_math_font_bool
      {
        \__siunitx_print_math_aux:N
          \mathbf \mathit \mathsf \mathtt
          \q_recursion_tail \q_recursion_stop
      }
      { \__siunitx_print_math_auxv:n }
        {#1}
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not be the most elegant solution, but you could force the `\SI{}{}` to be set as `\text` and then use `\bfseries` or `\textbf`. When using `siunitx` option `detect-all=true` the output is then bold.

I put an example below including a `\newcommand` to make your life a little easier.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, unicode-math, siunitx}
\sisetup{detect-all=true}

\newcommand{\bfqty}[2]{\text{\bfseries\SI{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
    \noindent
    xxxx $\mathbf{2 x = \text{\bfseries\SI{10}{\kilogram}}}$ xxxx\\
    xxxx $\mathbf{2 x = \bfqty{10}{\kilogram}}$ xxxx\\
        
    \noindent
    What I would like to have:\\
    xxxx $\symbf{2 x = 10\, kg}$ xxxx.\\
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**: A similar solution, where you do not have to put everything in a `text` environment would be the following. Note that here `detect-weight` will suffice, while you will need `detect-all` in the above example. You still need to put you entire equation in `\textbf{}` of `{\bfseries }` though.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec, unicode-math, siunitx}
\sisetup{
    mode=text,
    detect-weight=true,
}

\begin{document}
    \noindent
    xxxx \textbf{$\mathbf{2 x = \qty{10}{\kilo\gram}}$} xxxx\\
    \noindent
    What I would like to have:\\
    xxxx $\symbf{2 x = 10\, kg}$ xxxx.\\
\end{document}
```